# Handler from a non-Activity class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler, android-looper

Can we execute

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable,400)
```

from a non-`Activity` class?

I have a controller class, assume it as an adapter. Can we use `Handler` there?

I tried by debugging my app using break points, but the control is not reaching

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable,400)
```

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Actually I'm using OCR. If certain match is made, I want to return automatically to my main activity. I suppose its a looper. I need to capture the photograph of it also. For that I need to use a handler.

Comment: Of course you can use `handler` from a non-activity class. Why would you assume otherwise? A bit more info please. Where did you create the `Handler`? Where does control not reach? Also, `postDelayed()` returns boolean. Is it `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we execute `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 400)` from a non-`Activity` class?

Yes, you can.

Any [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is associated with a [`Thread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) (not an `Activity` or another object) and the `Thread`'s message queue. `Handlers` post/*process* [`Messages`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) and [`Runnables`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) to/*from* the queue that is handled by [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).

When you create a `Handler` within the main thread (e.g. in `Activity` class) you post/send messages and `Runnables` (with `post()`, `postDelayed()`, `sendMessage()` etc) to the running loop. However, by default, threads don't have the loop running unless you create one with the call to [`Looper.prepare()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#prepare()) first and [`Looper.loop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop()) afterwards.

In case a `Handler` created on a background thread is to post messages and `Runnables` to the main's thread queue either

- pass the main thread's `Looper` to the `Handler`'s [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler(android.os.Looper))
- or use `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`.

> I tried debugging my app using break points, but the control is not reaching.

I assume either your code logic never reaches "the control" or the `handler` is created within a background thread without preparing and looping `Looper` so that the `runnable` can't be processed by the `handler`.

Answer (score 0):

I used timer. It worked for me. LOL.

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(OcrCaptureActivity.TextBlockObject, textBlock.getValue());
            Log.d("Read Text : ", textBlock.getValue());
            Base.base_activity.setResult(CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS, data);
            Base.base_activity.finish();
        }
    }, POST_DELAYED_TIME);
```

Comment: You should use a Handler as has been suggested by @Onik. It's dead simple: `(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), delay);`

Using a TimerTask which is just another thread, you won't be able to update the UI if that ever becomes a thing.